# Ionic 2: bundle.js - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: angular, ionic2

I develop Ionic 2 app and stuck on this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js
```

I get blank screen when run app on android

Ionic version - 2.0.0-beta.36

Device - samsung s6/Android 6.0.1

Comment: do you have that file `app.bundle.js` in your `js` folder?

Comment: @ravishankar yes, I have. Also I tried `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`, but it didnt help